Issue with FullSimplify in StirlingS2 definition
I have previously asked a question about a problem simplifying an expression in Mathematica. The solution was to expand the definition of StirlingS2.
This time, I have a more complex set of functions:
p[k_, j_, n_, m_] := 
 StirlingS2[k, j]*Factorial[n*m]/(Factorial[(n*m) - j]*(n*m)^k)
ratio[n_, k_] := 
 Sum[p[k, j, n, 1]*KroneckerDelta[n, j]/Binomial[n, Min[n, j]], {j, 1,
    k}]

I know that simplified ratio equals to (Factorial[n]/(n^k))*StirlingS2[k, n].
If I use FullSimplify on ratio it doesn't work, so I tried to unwrap the StirlingS2 definition from the previous question and built this expressions:
stirlingS2[k_, j_, 
  r_] := (1/Factorial[j])*((-1)^(r + j))*Binomial[j, r]*r^k // 
  FullSimplify
p[k_, j_, n_, m_, r_] := 
 stirlingS2[k, j, r]*Factorial[n*m]/(Factorial[(n*m) - j]*(n*m)^k)
ratio[n_, k_] := 
 Sum[Sum[p[k, j, n, 1, r]  KroneckerDelta[n, j]/
       Binomial[n, Min[n, j]] // FullSimplify, {r, 0, j}] // 
   FunctionExpand, {j, 1, k}]

Now, when I simplify ratio this way: FullSimplify[ratio[n, k],  Assumptions -> {n \[Element] PositiveIntegers,  k \[Element] PositiveIntegers}] it doesn't output the correct simplified ratio.
How can I fix this issue? And how can I simplify these functions without having to modify them so much?

$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

p[k_, j_, n_, m_] := 
 StirlingS2[k, j]*Factorial[n*m]/(Factorial[(n*m) - j]*(n*m)^k)
ratio[n_, k_] := 
 Sum[p[k, j, n, 1]*KroneckerDelta[n, j]/Binomial[n, Min[n, j]], {j, 1, k}]

Using the Assumptions option in FullSimplify
FullSimplify[ratio[n, k], 
 Assumptions -> {n ∈ PositiveIntegers, 
   k ∈ PositiveIntegers}]

(* Sum[(n!*KroneckerDelta[j, n]*StirlingS2[k, j])/
     (n^k*(Binomial[n, Min[j, n]]*(-j + n)!)), {j, 1, k}] *)

The Assuming construct makes more thorough use of the assumptions, e.g., the assumptions are available to the intermediate Sum.
Assuming[{n ∈ PositiveIntegers, k ∈ PositiveIntegers}, 
 ratio[n, k] // FullSimplify]

(* Piecewise[{{1, k == 1}, {(n!*StirlingS2[k, n])/n^k, 
       k > 1 && k >= n}}, 0] *)

